# 3D Max Python selection multiple items on pymxs

Tags: python-3.x, scripting, 3dsmax

How to select faces from list on pymxs?

For example this code has the error: *Runtime error: operation requires a collection of nodes, got:*

```
from pymxs import runtime as rt

t = []
for face in rt.getCurrentSelection()[0].Faces:
    t.append(face)
rt.select(t)
```

And how to convert this code without "execute" and maxplus commands?

```
from pymxs import runtime as rt

rt.execute('subObjectLevel = 4')
```

is it possible to get list without recombine?

```
from pymxs import runtime as rt

object = rt.getCurrentSelection()[0]

for face in object.Faces:
    edges = rt.polyop.getEdgesUsingFace(object, face.index)
    for e in [x for x, edge in enumerate(edges, start=1) if edge]:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same approach as doing that in maxscript, ie use type-specific methods, polyop for editable poly, meshop for mesh:

```
from pymxs import runtime as rt

obj = rt.getCurrentSelection()[0]
rt.polyop.setFaceSelection(obj, rt.name('all'))
rt.subObjectLevel = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Additional question: is it possible to get a list without recombination? `[x for x, edge in enumerate(edges, start=1) if edge]`. I've added new code to topic.

Comment: You mean how to work with bitarrays? In python, working with them feels weird as they're converted to list of true/false values and don't have the niceties that they have maxscript side. You can always coerce them to array if need be, however in this case, just use polyop.getFaceEdges (getEdgesUsingFace is suitable for mutliple faces asi it goes through all the object edges and checks if they belong to one of the faces in the user supplied list).